# Toasting the result of wifi scan gives an error

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifimanager

I need to get the scan result as a toast but there is an error which I think in the syntax of the toast but I can not fix it

```
wifis = new String[wifiScanList.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < wifiScanList.size(); i++){
wifis[i] = ((wifiScanList.get(i)).toString());

Context context = getApplicationContext();
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, wifis, duration);
toast.show();
```

the program tills me to change wifis type to CharSequence but I need it as a string to get the info about each wifi network .. any idea!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, Arrays.toString(wifis), duration);
```

Comment: I did not try it yet as I have other issues ... I will update once I get a result

Comment: @user3082757 did you try this in the end?